# Spring Angular secure public api without authentication

Tags: angular, spring, api, spring-boot, spring-security

I have project built with Spring and Angular. There are two types of API end points in spring:

- Secured API: Only accessible for authorized user
- Public API: Accessible for all users

As I am getting unidentified api calls which is giving extra load to the server. Now, I need to **secure the public api without authentication** from being called anonymously i.e. prevent the API calls through curl or browser or postman. Also, I need to prevent the server from manual loop api calls and bot calls.

Since, everything is exposed in Angular side, I cannot add any extra fields to indicate the API call is from the official website.

Is there any way to secure the public endpoints?

Comment: Look at the `Spring Security` annotation `@PreAuthorize`.

Comment: @PreAuthorize works for logged in user, here I need to secure even if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Right. Use `@Preauthorize` (or `@Secured` for Role based access) on the endpoints that are access restricted and whitelist the public endpoints in your `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method with `antMatchers` and `permitAll`

Comment: Use Cors and allow only request from trusted origin. Or You can implement X509 certificate in case of multiple clients, where you will provide the client with X509 certificate(which you will share secretly) and in your spring security you can allow only requests which have valid X509 certificate.